# FOSUserBundle strange redirect after login in IE (to favicon)

Tags: redirect, authentication, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a strange redirects. Desired behavior is: when I type URL http://xyz.localhost there is a login form and after successful login I'm redirected to main page. Everything works well in firefox but fails in IE and Iron (which is Chrome) - redirects me to http://xyz.localhost/favicon.ico and of course there is routing error.

I removed favicon definition in base.html.twig in head section but result is same in Iron but now IE is working well.

I pasted [here](http://pastebin.com/43attPpq) content of dev.log file - only the part after pressing submit button.

I searched cache for "favicon" word and found it in compiled twig template:

```
/* WebProfilerBundle:Profiler:base.html.twig */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to UPLOAD favicon if it's missing and see what comes ;]